# Swift: Firebase auth observer not called if observers of child removed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, authentication, firebase

Assume `ref = Firebase(url: "your firebase url")`.
A child of ref would be `childRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("child")`

If I have `ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock` listening for authentication changes at ref, and I then use `childRef.removeAllObservers()`, the auth observer at ref is no longer listening for changes.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I crafted up a small app to duplicate the issue (ObjC code to follow)

The code to watch for auth'ing is:

```
[myRootRef observeAuthEventWithBlock:^(FAuthData *authData) {
    NSLog(@"got an auth event");
}];
```

and we have the child node

```
child = [myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"child_path"];
```

then the initial auth is

```
[myRootRef authUser:@"dude@thing.com" password:@"pw" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAuthData *authData) {

        NSLog(@"authentication 1 success");
        [child removeAllObservers];
        [self doAuth];
    } 
}];
```

The doAuth method simply auth's another user and outputs 'authentication 2 success'

```
got an auth event
got an auth event
authentication 1 success
authentication 2 success
```

So as you can see it worked as advertised - I was unable to duplicate the issue. My guess is the error may lie somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Alright, will check for other possible causes. Thanks!